# cargo-contract cannot build using the "stable" channel. Switch to nightly

Tags: substrate-node-template, ink, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

I want to run and build contract by thia command :

**Step 1:** `cargo contract new my_contract`

**Step 2:** `cargo contract build`

when i want to run **Step 2** and i faced this error :

> ERROR: cargo-contract cannot build using the "stable" channel. Switch to nightly. See https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract#build-requires-the-nightly-toolchain

**rustc Version :**

```
    cargo 1.69.0-nightly (82c3bb79e 2023-02-04)
release: 1.69.0-nightly
commit-hash: 82c3bb79e3a19a5164e33819ef81bfc2c984bc56
commit-date: 2023-02-04
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
libgit2: 1.5.0 (sys:0.16.0 vendored)
libcurl: 7.86.0-DEV (sys:0.4.59+curl-7.86.0 vendored ssl:OpenSSL/1.1.1q)
os: Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) [64-bit]
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the `cargo-contract` version. Pre 2.0.0 versions of `cargo-contract` use the nightly toolchain of rust. You can get it with `rustup toolchain add nightly` and then build with `cargo +nightly contract build`. You can omit the `+nightly` if you set the nightly toolchain as default with `rustup default nightly`.

ink! contracts where version < 4.0.0 need to be built with `cargo-contract` version < 2.0.0, therefore also with the nightly toolchain.

ink! 4 contracts need to be built with `cargo-contract` version 2 and can be built with both the stable and nightly toolchain.